# switched to older kernal now several installation doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, kernel

One day I Have to forcefully quit ubuntu without shutting down since it got hanged for more than half an hour. But when did I restarted it displayed some error again and agian and I didn't found any solution.One thing that I tired myself was on the boot menu I opened ubuntu from the older kernel available and was able to run ubuntu succesfully and is still running.

The problem arises in installing several softwares, like I was not able to run R interpeter etc

Currently I tried
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4 libappindicator1

which is a dependency for discord says this error:

```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
> linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
> but it is not going to be installed 
> linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic : Depends:
> linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed or
>                                                   linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be
> installed  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-45-generic : Depends:
> linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic but it is not going to be installed or
>                                                   linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-45-generic but it is not going to be
> installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no
> packages (or specify a solution).
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Lets first check your file system for errors. Then reboot to the newest kernel.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`